# Meaning - 'the subject can even be predicated of itself'

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source:](http://www.phil.pku.edu.cn/resguide/Kant/CPR/18.html) Ch 3,
Section 2, *Critique of Pure Reason*, by Kant, translated by Norman Kemp Smith

> I should have hoped to put an end to these idle and fruitless disputations in a direct manner, by an accurate determination of the concept of existence, had I not found that the illusion which is caused by the confusion of a logical with a real predicate (that is, with a predicate which determines a thing) is almost beyond correction. Anything we please can be made to serve as a logical predicate; **the subject can even be predicated of itself**; for logic abstracts from all content. But a determining predicate is a predicate which is added to the concept of the subject and enlarges it. Consequently, it must not be already contained in the concept.
>
> [predicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predicate) = [with object] 1. {Grammar & Logic} state, affirm, or assert (something) about the subject of a sentence or an argument of a proposition

I recast [user John Lawler's comment:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158797/to-predicate-of-or-as-or-some-other-preposition#comment330774_158797) Denote A a human agent, P a predicate; X the argument of P.
A predicates P of X   =   P is predicated by A of X   =    Say( A, P(X) ).

Yet I remain confused. I don't see any human agent here,  How do you determine/deduce the meaning of the bolded? How can a subject predicate itself?

Footnote: This bolded phrase features as the first Example Sentence at [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predicate).

Comment: It is what it is. Satellites are out tonight; let x equal x.

Comment: *a subject can be predicated of itself* ≠ "a subject predicate[s] itself"

Answer (score 1):

Kant's sentence is a passive, so neither the predicating Agent (John Lawler's *A*) nor the preposition *by* which marks it is required to be present. In John Lawler's construction

> P is predicated <s>by A</s> of X = Say( [A,] P(X))

Kant puts forward an agentless construction in which the "subject" of the predication, X, is also the predicate, P:

> X is predicated of X ... *for example*
>   A rose is a rose is a rose.
>   Boys will be boys.
>   Whatever will be will be.