# What does 'of' mean in 'to be predicated of'?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I can't pinpoint why, but the **OF** in **to be predicated OF** has been bothering me. I read [user John Lawler's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158797/to-predicate-of-or-as-or-some-other-preposition#comment330774_158797), but still don't understand [user TRomano's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48768/meaning-the-subject-can-even-be-predicated-of-itself#comment90848_48768) .

Please pinpoint which definition of [**OF**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of)  matches the use in: **to be predicated OF**?
Please ensure to specify its number (as per ODO's enumeration of the many definitions).

Comment: For some reason, the *somewhy* in your question bothers me. Maybe because the only two entries in the OED for this word are from 1861 +/- three years. Are you trying to write in esoteric, outdated, rare English?

Comment: @δοῦλος Sorry for any confusion. No; I'm trying to use the shortest words whenever possible, because I worry that long posts may discourage people.

Comment: Using esoteric language discourages me.

Comment: @δοῦλος I'm sorry. I had thought that if this figured in http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=somewhy, then it'd be fine.

Comment: It cannot be predicated of Law Area 51 Proposal - Commit (hereinafter "LA51PC") that LA51PC is in possession of a decent dictionary.

Comment: @TRomano Sorry for the long name; I'm just trying to promote that proposal. I did try [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/predicate_2) but which fails to discuss this. Given my difficulty with ODO already, [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149844?rskey=amTvMG&result=2&isAdvanced=false) worsens my confusion. Are there better simple dictionaries other than ODO?

Comment: I would recommend that you try the *Larousse UNABRIDGED Dictionary FRENCH/ENGLISH-- English/French Dictionary* or the New Oxford American Dictionary (2010). Nothing with "Concise" or "Abridged" in the title.  A book, not an online edition.

Comment: @snailboat Thank you for your support. Yes of course; I'm here to learn. Is it an interesting question, why 'somewhy' obsolesced, but 'somewhat' and 'somehow' and the like, prevailed?

Comment: @snailboat If anyone's interested, I asked the above here: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237572/50720

Comment: It seems like the Oxford Dictionary has slipped up on this one. If you look in the Cambridge Dictionary, you will find  **of** *preposition* **(RELATING TO)**
​ *about; relating to*   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of

Answer (score 2):

**It can (honestly) be *said of* Yao Ming that he is tall.**

The preposition *of* there means something a little different than *about*. One might paraphrase that statement so:

*Tallness is a quality that Yao Ming has, and to say so is to speak the truth.*

When we predicate a quality or property *of* a subject, we are stating that the subject possesses that quality or property.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please just identify which definition of **of** and the number from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) matches the use here?

Comment: Will you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the questioner and answerer are speaking about the same kind of predicate (rhymes with Kate).

In linguistics, the verb "to predicate" is closely bound to the noun "predicate", and means, roughly, as others have stated , "to say something [about X] ". In this sense, you can reasonably say "A predicates X **of** B."

Outside of linguistics, "predicated" is almost always paired with **on** (or, not so commonly nowadays, **upon**), which means something more like "dependent on": (that is, if "B is predicated **on** A", it means that B cannot occur unless A occurs first.

- The success of the launch is **predicated on** the skill of the engineers.
- "There is a law, irrevocably decreed in Heaven before the foundations of this world, **upon** which all blessings are **predicated**—and when we obtain any blessing from God, it is by obedience to that law **upon which it is predicated**." (Doctrine & Covenants 130:20–21)

Oh, and as to the question about the meaning of "of" in "predicated **of**: the *of* is used in sense 5 as listed in ODO:

- "indicating the relationship between a verb and an indirect object"

Comment: Done. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry to bother you again, but may I ask if you could please expand on this meaning of "of" here? I see that it `indicates the relationship between a verb and an indirect object`, but what more can be said? 'of' still confuses me.

Comment: Just substitute "said about" for predicated of".  As I wrote in my answer above, _A predicates X of B_ means _A says X about B._

Comment: Thanks again. I understand the meaning of the sentence `A predicates X of B`. However, I was asking only about the preposition **of** here. It still feels strange to me. Would you please be able to explain more?

Comment: Sorry it sounds strange to you. I hope you can get used to it.