# 'require from' vs 'require of'

Tags: difference, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/require): **require something of** = Regard an action, ability, or quality as due from (someone) by virtue of their position

['of' in phrasal verbs, still confuses me](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/48769/8712). 1. Which [ODO definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/of?q=OF#of) applies?

2. What are the similarities and differences between 'require from' vs 'require of'?

Please tell me if this example is irrelevant; I am asking in general and not only about this usage, but why not **'require of'**? [Source: Thomas Jefferson to Robert R. Livingston, 18 April 1802](http://founders.archives.gov/documents/Jefferson/01-37-02-0220)

> ...but writing by mr Dupont [de Nemours], I need use no cypher. I **require from** him to put this into your own & no other hand, let the delay occasioned by that be what it will.

Comment: You sure the usage hasn't been changed over time? (I don't have access to ngrams and such)

Comment: @MARamezani I'm not completely sure, no, but modern usages also confuse me. I only picked this quote from Jefferson for Jefferson's with excellent writing.

Comment: Emperor Stoney is available in chat. I'll call him to give this a look. :)

Comment: It is **by definition** entirely hopeless to try to understand the meaning of an idiom as derivable from the meanings of its parts.

Comment: @StoneyB (To: MARamezani also) Thanks. I didn't realise at all that this was an idiom!

Comment: Hey @StoneyB why don't you put that down as an answer so it can be voted up?

Comment: @Omnidisciplinarianist Because it's not an answer: it's an assertion of non-answerability.

Answer (score 1):

This would be sense 6: "Indicating the relationship between a verb and an indirect object." Sense 6 has two subsenses ("With a verb expressing a mental state" and "Expressing a cause"), but neither of them seems particularly relevant, so that's as far as ODO takes us.

There are no universal rules for which verbs use which prepositions to construe their arguments; rather, you generally have to learn the right prepositions as part of learning the verb.